# Designing an amplifier circuit with coupling capacitors

Tags: amplifier, pspice, circuit-design

I am attempting to do the following:

> Design an amplifier circuit consisting of input and output coupling capacitors (\$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$), a voltage source (\$V_s\$), a source resistor (\$r_s\$), an output resistor (\$r_0\$), and load resistor (\$R_L\$). Choose the resistances for input and output resistors of the amplifier, and the source resistor by yourself. Suppose the two sub cutoff frequencies (\$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$) are equal to each other (\$f_1 = f_2\$). The lower cutoff frequency (\$f_L\$) of the overall circuit is 50 Hz. The mid-band gain \$|V_L / V_s|\$ in terms of decibels is 100 dB.
>
> a. Draw the circuit diagram, label input and output terminals, and show the component values of your design.

I have already designed the circuit in PSpice as shown below, but I'm not getting any output. What am I doing wrong?

[image: PSpice Schematic]

Comment: Show us the schematic for what you've done already, describe the problem you're having, what you've done to troubleshoot it.

Comment: heres the circuit ive designed in pspice..

Comment: If you're looking for 100dB of gain in the mid band you can't get there with a single stage common emitter amplifier.  In fact with this circuit you have a gain of less than 2. (6 dB).  I haven't looked at the biasing, but what is the DC voltage at the collector of the transistor?

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

If you follow the following steps you will find out what the main problem is.
You will find it useful to work out how to follow similar "trouble shooting procedures on other circuits.

- Look at your DC biasing and work out what the DC voltages will be at various points in the circuit.
- Draw conclusions about what will happen as a result.
- Makes changes.

Report back.

---

What is the voltage at Q1b (Q1 base) ?
(Hint: Set by R3 R4 and V1).

What is the voltage at Q1e (Q1 emitter) ?
(Hint: Less than Q1b by a Vbe drop of ABOUT 0.6V).

As the voltage at Q1e appears across R2 what is the approximate current in R2
[Hint: Ohm's law].

The current in R1 and R2 is about the same.
As R1 is about 2 x R2, what will the approximate voltage across R1 be?
[You can use the fact that R1 = 2 x R1 t work out R1 voltage drop
OR use the current from the previous step to work out V_R1 - either method gives the same result].

If you add up V_R1 and V_R2 and compare the voltage with what is available from V1, what do you conclude?